Синонимизировать метки на тему [чат]
Предлагаю синонимизировать следующие метки:

chat (94 вопроса) описания нет
чат (84 вопроса) есть описание

Основная - чат, т. к. она на русском.

Готово!
updating post history, 104 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 94 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 89 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'chat': [chat] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 173
tag remapping of [чат] and [chat] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym chat -> чат was approved!

